# Are there any binary red supergiants?

Tags: supernova, space, binary-star, observable-universe, red-giant

I wonder if we ever have identified or observed a pair of binary stars (red supergiants). And I also wonder what would happen if they exploded, (theoretically) as we haven’t observed it. Also, would currently existing binary stars have enough mass to later on burn out into a red giant, and then explode as a supernova, and would it affect us?

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_star#Binary_neutron_stars

Comment: Crossposted from https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/732776/2451